# Zip uneven numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following `numpy.arrays`:

```
a = np.array([1., 2., 3.])
b = np.array([4., 5.])
c = np.array([6., 7.])
```

I need to combine these so I end up with the following:

```
[(1., 4., 6.), (1., 5., 7.), (2., 4., 6.), (2., 5., 7.), (3., 4., 6.), (3., 5., 7.)]
```

Note that in this case, the array `a` happens to be the largest array. This is not guaranteed however. Nor is the length guaranteed. In other words, any array could be the longest and each array is of arbitrary length.

I tried using `itertools.izip_longest` but I can only use `fillvalue` for the tuple with `3.` which will not work. I tried `itertools.product` also but my result is not a true cartesian product.

Comment: What exactly do you want this to do when `a` isn't the largest array?

Comment: You say `each array is of arbitrary length`. So, if `b` and `c` have different sizes, I don't see how you could get an output. Consider adding another sample input-output to cover such a case?

Comment: Should have clarified. All arrays are the same size except the large one. So for example, `a` can be of length `m` but `b` and `c` will be of the same length `n`.

Comment: And all arrays would be 1D arrays?

Comment: It might be easier to find the largest list (`[len(x) for x in ...]`), and move that to the start, or othewise treat it as special.  That will let you focus on the core issue - generating all the combinations.

Comment: In your example, the 1st is handled different from the rest.  Is that because it is first, or because it is longest?  What do you want when the 2nd or 3rd is longest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transpose `b` and `c` and then create a product of the `a` with the transposed array using `itertools.product`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [np.insert(j,0,i) for i,j in product(a,np.array((b,c)).T)]
[array([ 1.,  4.,  6.]), array([ 1.,  5.,  7.]), array([ 2.,  4.,  6.]), array([ 2.,  5.,  7.]), array([ 3.,  4.,  6.]), array([ 3.,  5.,  7.])]
>>>
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but it doesn't work when `a` is not the largest array

Comment: @LRP It might also has more scenarios, which OP doesn't explained them. Anyway I just answered based on OP's question.

Comment: The original post specifies that `a` might not be the largest array: "Note that in this case, the array `a` happens to be the largest array. This is not guaranteed however."

Comment: @strimp099 So what would be your expected output if `b` and `c` don't have same length?

Comment: I added a comment above covering this point which I failed to discuss in the OP. All arrays are the same size except the large one. So for example, `a` can be of length `m` but `b` and `c` will be of the same length `n`.

Comment: @strimp099 So in that case you won't have any problem?

Comment: Yes your solution seems to be working. Still testing.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have:

```
a = np.array([4., 5.])
b = np.array([1., 2., 3.])
c = np.array([6., 7.])
d = np.array([5., 1])
e = np.array([3., 2.])
```

Now, if you know before-hand which one is the longest array, which is `b` in this case, you can use an approach based upon [`np.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) -

```
# Concatenate elements from identical positions from the equal arrays 
others = np.vstack((a,c,d,e)).T # If you have more arrays, edit this line

# Get grided version of the longest array and 
# grided-indices for indexing into others array
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(others.shape[0]),b)

# Concatenate grided longest array and grided indexed others for final output
out = np.hstack((Y.ravel()[:,None],others[X.ravel()]))
```

Sample run -

```
In [47]: b
Out[47]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])

In [48]: a
Out[48]: array([ 4.,  5.])

In [49]: c
Out[49]: array([ 6.,  7.])

In [50]: d
Out[50]: array([ 5.,  1.])

In [51]: e
Out[51]: array([ 3.,  2.])

In [52]: out
Out[52]: 
array([[ 1.,  4.,  6.,  5.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  5.,  7.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  4.,  6.,  5.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  5.,  7.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  6.,  5.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  5.,  7.,  1.,  2.]])
```

Comment: @Kasramvd's solution seems to provide the incorrect result with this use case and runs slower (80 µs v. 30 µs).

Comment: This solution returns an nd array where I'm looking for a list of arrays or list of tuples.

Comment: @strimp099 You can use `out.tolist()` to convert to list of lists. Or use `np.split(out,range(1,len(out)))` for list of arrays, whichever suits your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If the length differences are not extreme (check inputs first) I'd be tempted to pad out the shorter lists to the length of the longest with None and generate all the permutations (27 of them for 3 lists of 3 elements). Then

```
 results = []
 for candidate in possibles:
    if not (None in candidate): results.append(candidate)
```

Reasons not to do this: if the cube of the length of the longest list is significant in terms of memory usage (space to store N cubed possibles) or CPU usage.